# How to implement recursion in my c++ code

Tags: c++, recursion

Am trying to solve a codewars kata called persistent bugger with the following instructions:

> Write a function, persistence, that takes in a positive parameter num and returns its   multiplicative persistence, which is the number of times you must multiply the digits in num until you reach a single digit.

3
I have finished one iteration but can't quite figure out how to make the function loop it self

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int persistence(int n){
    int counter=0;
    int temp=1;
    vector<int> arry;

    while(n!=0){
        arry.push_back(n%10);
        n/=10;
    }
    if(arry.size()==1){                   //--eliminate single digit numbers
        return 0;
    }
    for(int x=0;x<arry.size();x++){
        temp*=arry[x];
        n=temp;                          
    }
    counter++;

    return counter;
}

int main(){
    int number=999;
    cout<<persistence(number);
return 0;
}
```

I tried using recursion to solve this but failed since i lack the knowledge on how to properly use recursion.Thank you for your time

Comment: If you know how to call a function, you know how to do recursion.

Comment: Do you succeed to do it iteratively?

Comment: I'm not quite following, but I think you should replace `return counter;` with `return 1 + persistence(temp);`. (and get rid of the `counter` variable).

Comment: In this example, as in almost all situations, recursion is not a good approach. Write a function that multiplies the digits in a number and returns the product. Call that function in a loop, exiting the loop when the number is less than 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters using the standard container `std::vector` does not make sense.

I would write a recursive function the following way

```
#nclude <iostream>

unsigned int multiplication( unsigned int n )
{
    const unsigned int Base = 10;

    return n == 0 ? 1 : n % Base * multiplication( n / Base );
}

size_t persistence( unsigned int n )
{
    const unsigned int Base = 10;

    return n < Base ? 0 : 1 + persistence( multiplication( n ) );
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << persistence( 39 ) << '\n';
    std::cout << persistence( 999 ) << '\n';
    std::cout << persistence( 4 ) << '\n';
}
```

The program output is

```
3
4
0
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you had a function `digit_product` that multiplies the digits of a number.

Then you could write this:

```
int persistence(int x)
{
    int product = digit_product(x);
    return product < 10 ? 0 : 1 + persistence(product);
}
```

And `digit_product` is equally complicated:

```
int digit_product(int x)
{
    return x < 10 ? x : (x % 10 * digit_product(x/10));
}
```